# ArrayList<Integer> in GridView

Tags: gridview, arraylist, baseadapter

I want to fill a GridView via a GridAdapter which extends the BaseAdapter.
I've only found Tutorials, in which they explained, how to fill a GridView with a 
ArrayList. I'm not able to do this for a ArrayList.

```
 private static final class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    final ArrayList<Integer> mItems;
    final int mCount;

    private GridAdapter(final ArrayList<Integer> items){
        mCount = items.size();
        mItems = new ArrayList<Integer>(mCount);
        for (int i = 0; i<=items.size(); i++){
            mItems.add(items.get(i));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return mCount;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(final int position){
        return mItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(final int position){
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent){
        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null){
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
        }

        final TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        text.setText(mItems.get(position));
        return view;
    }
}
```

Every time when I run the app on my Android, the app force closes.

Comment: I guess last `}` is typo.

Comment: ok, i've solved the problem.
Now I have another problem:
When I change a  Number in the ArrayList, how can I update the GridView?